# Swift 5 Codable - API provides sometimes an value sometimes not

Tags: swift, api, struct, codable

I have Codables running now. But from API sometime **Example Was Coming** and sometimes **example was not coming**. I was searching here and found this

below are images with example element or without example elemnt

**With Example**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYQek.png)

**Without example**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85F1v.png)

> i have created structure for this but this is not work. because example was coming or

```
struct Defination: Codable {
var definition: String
var synonyms: [String]
var antonyms: [String]
var example: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case definition
    case synonyms
    case antonyms
    case example
}
```

}

Comment: If "example" is optional, then make it an optional String, like: var example: String?

Comment: Thank you @Shadowrun for give me your precious time to solve my problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can create like this type structure, if you have a any value are sometime coming or sometime not coming so that value you write like this.

`var example: String?`

only write **?** end of the DataType

> this answer given by [@Shadowrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4773610/shadowrun)